# Where is the fake window with a wing cap in the Castle Grounds?

Tags: b3313

The B3313 wiki page for the [Castle Grounds](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Castle_Grounds) states that if you spawn in the Nighttime Castle Grounds, "The fake window containing a wing cap block is removed". However, it doesn't say where this fake window is during the normal daytime version of the Castle Grounds.

Is there actually a fake window with a wing cap block in the daytime Castle Grounds? If so, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the castle, where the Toad statue *mostly*(*) is, on the left side of the back door, try and climb in the left-most window.

[image]

[image]

This is probably the intended way to access the [Redacted], as the Toad in Crescent Castle seems to hint.

> I SWEAR, THESE BOB-OMBS ARE FAULTY OR SOMETHING...THERE'S THAT ONE IN A ROOM MADE OF BRICKS...SOMEWHERE IN THE CASTLE. I FEEL LIKE IT'S HIDING SOMETHING...I WOULD CHECK THE WINDOWS, BUT I CAN'T JUMP THAT HIGH

---

(*) *at least until the AI decides it is not*

Comment: What is "the [Redacted]"? I assumed that hint referred to the fake windows in the [Orange Hall](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Orange_Hall).

Comment: @Stevoisiak In the Castle Ground you can use the Wing Cap to access a secret passage that takes you to a **room made of bricks** with a **faulty Bob-Ombs** stuck in the ground. Since the first part of the hint simply **has** to be about that room, I assume that "checking the windows" is an hint for finding the Wing Cap in the same hub area. There are many other ways to access the "brick room", the most obvious one being falling from the Floating Hotel and thus ending up on the roof.

Comment: @Stevoisiak To put this into context, check the page about the [Castle Grounds](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Castle_Grounds) and the note about the exit to [Redacted](https://b3313.fandom.com/wiki/Twisted_Red_Hallway) (trying to keep spoilers to minimum since you may want to find out yourself)